# How to build OSX 64bit application in Tokyo

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

How do I build applications for 64bit OSX with Delphi Tokyo ?
Or is there another Delphi version that can do this ?

All I can find is OSX 32bit, where is the option to link for 64bit ?

I am using  Delphi 10.2 Version 25.0.26309.314

Comment: Simple: there is no compiler for macos64

Comment: Contrary to what the Embarcadero website says, this means that you cannot submit apps to the app store.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot make 64bit OSX apps in 10.2 Tokyo, as it does not have a 64bit compiler for OSX, only a 32bit compiler.  Support for 64bit OSX is slated in [the current roadmap](https://community.embarcadero.com/article/16563-rad-studio-roadmap-september-2017) for release in 10.3.